# Matlab - seemingly simple instruction causes high cpu load

Tags: matlab

I am writing a Matlab script that implements a noisegate algorithm. It iterates over the length of an input signal (which I created in the same script) and processes sample by sample. The algorithm itself doesn't require much memory (it carries over two values to the next iteration, namely `x_peak_old` and `g_old`). However, to monitor the internal process of the algorithm, I created some additional debug vectors that are the same length of the input signal and get updated with each loop. I comment them in and out as needed.

However, my problem is that one of these vectors behaves strangely. If I disable this vector and hit 'Run', the script executes and finishes in an instant. However, when I assign values to this specific vector each loop and run the script, it takes several seconds to compute and one core of my CPU is at 100% load during this time.

Here's the code:

```
clear all; close all;

% ***** Parameter *****
Fs = 44100; % Samplerate
ta = 5; % Attack time in ms
tr = 300; % Release time in ms
th = -8; % Threshold in dB
R = 0.05; % Ratio in dB/dB

% ***** Test signal *****
f0 = 20000; % Frequency in Hz
a = (0:Fs) ./ Fs;
aflip = fliplr(a);
sine = sin((2 * pi * f0 / Fs) .* (0:Fs));
sinedecay = zeros(1, Fs);
for k = 1:(Fs+1)
    sinedecay(k) = sine(k)*aflip(k);
end
zeropad = zeros(1, Fs);
% Sine only
% x = [zeropad sine sinedecay zeropad];
% Triangle Rectangle Sine
x = [zeropad a (1-a) -a a-1 zeropad ones(1, Fs) (-1).*ones(1,Fs) zeropad sine sine sinedecay zeropad];
% Dirac
%x = [zeropad 1 zeropad];
siglen = length(x);
x_axis = (1:siglen) ./ Fs;

% ***** Output signal *****
y = zeros(1, siglen);

% ***** Debug signals *****
%threshold = 10^(th/20) .* ones(1, siglen);
%xpeakt = zeros(1, siglen);
%peaklogt = zeros(1, siglen);
%ctrl_logt = zeros(1, siglen);
f_t = zeros(1, siglen);
gt = zeros(1, siglen);

% ***** Derived parameters *****

AT = 1/(1+ta*Fs/1000);
RT = 1-1/(1+tr*Fs/1000);
TH_log = log2( 10^(th/20));
S = 1 - 1/R;

% ***** Initial parameters *****

x_peak_old = 0;
g_old = 0;

% ***** Lets go! *****

for i = 1:siglen 

% Peak measurement
    p0 = abs(x(i));
    x_peak = x_peak_old * RT;
    if (p0 > x_peak)
        x_peak = p0 * AT + x_peak_old *(1-AT);
    end
    x_peak_old = x_peak;
%    xpeakt(i) = x_peak; % DEBUG
    x_peak_log = log2(x_peak);
%    peaklogt(i) = x_peak_log; % DEBUG

% Compare with threshold

    ctrl_log = TH_log - x_peak_log;
    if (ctrl_log < 0)
        ctrl_log = 0;
    end
%    ctrl_logt(i) = ctrl_log; %DEBUG

% Calculation of weight factor

    f = S * ctrl_log;
    f_t(i) = f; %DEBUG
    g = 2^f;

% Smoothing filter for weight factor
    if (g > g_old) 
        coeff = 1-AT;
    else
        coeff = 1-RT;
    end
    temp = g;    
    g = coeff * g + (1-coeff) * g_old;
    g_old = temp;

    % THE FOLLOWING LINE CAUSES PROBLEMS
    gt(i) = g; % DEBUG

% Calculation output signal
    y(i) = x(i) * g;
end

% ***** Plot input, output and debug signals *****
figure;
subplot(211);
plot(x_axis, x);
hold on; grid on;
%plot(x_axis, threshold);
%plot(x_axis, xpeakt); %DEBUG
%plot(x_axis, peaklogt); %DEBUG
%plot(x_axis, ctrl_logt); %DEBUG
plot(x_axis, f_t); %DEBUG
%plot(x_axis, gt); %DEBUG
subplot(212);
plot(x_axis, y);
```

The line that is causing the issues is the one near the end:

```
gt(i) = g; % DEBUG
```

However, just a few lines before, in the same loop, I assing a value to a vector the same way:

```
f_t(i) = f; %DEBUG
```

Both vectors are initialized the same way. There are more vectors in this loop that are treated the exact same way, but it is only the `gt(i)` vector that behaves odd.

I tested this script on two different machines running Matlab R2014b. What is causing this issue?

Comment: huh.... Interesting

Comment: I can definitely reproduce this in 2014b. ~0.1s vs ~12s. Profiling does not give more insight.

Comment: Thus **must** be because the JIT does not optimize something when that line is ther.

Comment: I think i found the root of the issue - gt() seems to also be a builtin function equivalent to the '>' operator. Simply renaming the vector gt to something else resolves it. D'oh!

Comment: Interestingly, if you replace the line by `if ii~=1; gt(ii-1) = g;end` in the begging of the `for` loop, it will make it way faster. Still slower than without the code, but faster.

Comment: @UnbescholtenerBuerger please add an asnwer. This is interesting for the community.Shadowing builtins does reduce the speed a lot it seems!

Comment: Okay I did that. Is there any way to toggle a warning if you accidentaly mask builtins?

Comment: I don't think so, unfortunatedly

Comment: @UnbescholtenerBuerger, there is no way to toggle an automatic warning, but if you're in doubt about a variable name shadowing a built in function name, use the command [`which`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html) before using the variable, it will tell you if this name is mapped to a built in function (or even a function of your own in the search path).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the name of your variable `gt` to something else (other than the name of a built-in function).

---

I think this is exactly the case The Mathworks warn you about when they tell you that it is not recommended to overload built-in function.

The [`gt`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gt.html) function is the full form of the shorthand operator `>`.

Before running the script:

```
>> which gt
built-in (C:\TLAB13a\toolbox\matlab\ops\@double\gt)  % double method
```

And after running your script:

```
>> which gt
gt is a variable.
```

---

I can reproduce the described behaviour in Matlab R2013a (~7.5s with the debug variable, 0.1s without).

Note that on R2016a this behaviour is inexistant (~0.12s for both versions). The newer Matlab engine are not so easily confused by overloaded built in functions.

---

In your case, and for people using older Matlab version, just changing the variable name from `gt` to anything else (other than the name of another built-in function), `gtx` for example, make the script run fine and fast even with the debug variables.

Answer (score 3):

Found the shenanigans. Apparently the issue is caused by the vector's name `gt`, which is also a builtin function equivalent to '>' operator. Overriding that has a big impact on speed. Simply renaming the vector solved the problem.

Comment: I can confirm that this happen with several other builtins. Lesson to learn: Shadowing builtins will slow your code by a lot!